# How to retrieve the data from stripe responses using php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Here is my php code for stripe transaction for taking the application fee from customer using my platform:

```
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(
  array(
    "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "Event charge",
    "application_fee" => 123 // amount in cents
  ),
  array("stripe_account" => $sInfo->stripe_user_id)
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($charge);
```

and here is my response (partial)

```
Stripe\Charge Object
(
[_opts:protected] => Stripe\Util\RequestOptions Object
    (
        [headers] => Array
            (
                [Stripe-Account] => acct_16JkaUHzfYmjyH68
            )

        [apiKey] => sk_test_mHnhDuaVjnKmdkEApnYAKfGY
    )

[_values:protected] => Array
    (
        [id] => ch_16K6q5HzfYmjyH786HG5a2gp
        [object] => charge
        [created] => 1435840249
        [livemode] => 
        [paid] => 1
        [status] => succeeded
        [amount] => 1000
        [currency] => usd
        [refunded] => 
        [source] => Stripe\Card Object
```

i am having difficulty for how i can catch the the value "id => ch_16K6q5HzfYmjyH786HG5a2gp" from _values:protected array

i have tried the following syntaxes

```
$charge->_values:protected and $charge['_values:protected']
```

but not able to grab the response, can any one here to help to catch the response in stripe connect transactions using php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this instead of dumping the entire object

`print $charge->id;`

Comment: and for other inner arrays also it worked as the same way $charge->source->id or $charge->source->last4 , $charge->source->fingerprint etc. thanks again

Answer (score 11):

For anyone that may come across this, Stripe's PHP library has a function to create an array

```
public function jsonSerialize()
{
    return $this->__toArray(true);
}
```

Use this to get an workable Array from the Object.
Ex.

```
$charge->jsonSerialize();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this to convert object to simple array form

```
$charge->__toArray(TRUE);
```